# Can't call an object method. PHP reports variable undefined

Tags: php

This is the weirdest bug!  It is probably something silly, but I have no idea how to fix it.  If anyone could help, I would be most grateful!  I have three files, one is called items.php, another is called tableFunctions.php, and the third is called mysql.php.  I use two global objects called 'mysql' and 'tableFunctions'.  They are stored in the files 'mysql.php', and 
'tableFunctions.php', respectively.  In each file, I create an instance of its object, assigning it to the global variable $_mysql, or $_table.  like this:

In the file mysql.php:

```
global $_mysql;
$_mysql = new mysql();
```

In the file tableFunctions.php:

```
global $_table;
$_table = new tableFunctions();
```

Here's how it is supposed to work:

The items.php file includes the tableFunctions.php file...
Which in turn, needs the mysql.php file, so it includes it too.

In the items.php file, I call the method getTable(), which is contained in the object tableFunctions.(and in the variable $_table.) Like this:

```
$t = $_table->getTable('items');
```

The getTable function calls the method, arrayFromResult(), which is contained within in the object mysql.(and in the variable $_mysql.) Like this:

```
$result  = $_mysql->arrayFromResult($r);
```

That's where I get the error.  PHP says that the variable '$_mysql' is undefined, but I defined it in the 'mysql.php' file.(see above)  I also included mysql.php with the following code:

```
include_once 'mysql.php';
```

I have no idea what is wrong!  If anyone can help that would be much appreciated.
The source files can be downloaded with the following link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bjj2gyjsybym89r/YLxqyNvQdn

Comment: Please, read some books like "Clean code" or "Code complete", it's impossible to read such dirty code.

Comment: @OZ_  in what way is my code dirty?  Do I need more spaces?

Comment: @zerkms globals are not evil, though some _coders_ are ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a common mistake, in the place of definition you need only the line:

```
$_mysql = new mysql();
```

and when you want to use it inside a function, only there you have to declare it as a global variable (otherwise it is considered like any other function variable):

```
global $_mysql;
```

so, for example, if we'll take your method:

```
function getTable($tableName) {         
        $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
            err($r, 'mysql returned null when getting table!');

        $result  = $_mysql->arrayFromResult($r);
        return $result;
    }
```

it should be changed to:

```
function getTable($tableName) {
        global $_mysql;
        $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
            err($r, 'mysql returned null when getting table!');

        $result  = $_mysql->arrayFromResult($r);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Could I even access the variable $_mysql within a function to make it global?

Comment: when you declared it outside the function - it is already global (unless it's inside a class). when you declare a parameter as "global" inside a function it tells the PHP interpreter to look for that parameter in the global environment instead of the function scope.

Comment: So you mean that that basically tells the function to refer to the variable "by reference".

Comment: no, "by reference" is another thing which is unrelated to this discussion. It "tells" the function to refer to the variable which is defined in the global environment which is outside of the function's scope.

Comment: OK, "by reference" or not, your suggestion worked. I really appreciate you going the extra mile by actually downloading my source code and checking the whole thing out.